# gas optimize an if or else statement

Tags: contract-development, gas, optimization

if staking a tokenX the contract needs to set the state variables accordingly, and if staking a tokenY set the other state variables.
i have various helper functions for this but was wondering what the most gas efficient way of doing this was.
option 1: two separate functions for each specific call
option 2: one function that takes the param of the token type (X | Y) and has an if X ... else ...

If option 2 is more gas efficient what is the best way to store X and Y?
bool: true | false,
int: 0 | else
string: 'x'|else
?
just curious and am looking at various ways for optimizing gas

Answer (score 0):

This kind of things are usually easiest to just try out, and measure the gas usage.

As a rule of thumb, use the smallest possible variable type (for example booleans). There are lots of different optimizations that can be tried (for example tight packing ([Efficient Bit Packing](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/77099/efficient-bit-packing))).

On the other hand, you should also consider code readability. Clear and easy to understand code increases trust, since more people are able to read what it does. So it's always a trade off between efficiency and readability.

Also, you'll need to consider whether you want to optimize for deployment or usage (or both).